# random display categories - change url

Tags: php, categories

This part of my script runs WordPress categories and displays them in a random order.

The problem I'm having is that the url is based upon the categories `ID`
There's one category that should go to a different page if clicked in stead of the categories page.

So I created a variable and kicked in the url. Created a `if`-statement to see when the `$cat_id` is loaded and then change it.

But it only outputs the url multiple times (every found category)

What can it be?

```
$category_link = get_category_link( $cat_id );
$custom_link = get_option( 'home' ).'/sub/sub-sub';
echo '
    <div class="carousel_items">
        <div class="category_image">
            <a href="'.($cat_id == 5) ? esc_url($custom_link) : esc_url( $category_link ).'">
                <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/svg/'.$cat_id.'.svg" />
            </a>
        </div>
   </div>';
```

Comment: It's outputting the custom_link or the category_link? I assume this is inside a foreach or similar?

Comment: Sorry. Yes this is within a `foreach` and it's outputting the `$custom_link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are concatenating the result to a href you must wrap the ifelse statement inside another set of parentheses so the result is calculated first and then returned:

```
<a href="'.(($cat_id == 5) ? esc_url($custom_link) : esc_url($category_link)).'">
```

Comment: No I did not and I will thank you for this good sir!!!